# appendChild not working with audio control

Tags: javascript, audio, appendchild

I am dynamically creating an audio control and attempting to show it on a form with controls. I have div on the form (I've tried it with div, td, span) and I am positive I have its id correct. I am using appendChild(audio). If I put an alert() just before the function ends, the audio control will begin playing the file. As soon as the function exits, the audio player stops and I never see the control displayed. What am I missing? It seems obvious the audio variable loses scope and is no longer valid. But why can't I appendChild it to my div, td, or span? (I am in firefox, so its the ogg that is playing)

Edit - I suppose I should mention that this is being called from

HTML:

```
<a onclick="CreateAudio($oggfile, $id)">Play</a>
```

javascript:

```
function CreateAudio(oggfile, id)
{ 
var audio = document.createElement('audio');

var source= document.createElement('source');
source.type= 'audio/ogg';
source.src= oggfile;
audio.appendChild(source);

mp3file = oggfile;  // I will fix this to replace ogg extension with mp3
source= document.createElement('source');
source.type= 'audio/mpeg';
source.src= mp3file;
audio.appendChild(source);

var div = document.getElementById(id);
div.appendChild(audio);

audio.load;
audio.play();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The audio element you originally created loses scope when the function is finished. You'll need to access the audio element that's in the DOM.

```
audio.setAttribute("id", "myAudioClip")
var div = document.getElementById(id);
div.appendChild(audio);
var audioElement = document.getElementById("myAudioClip");

audioElement.load();
audioElement.play();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am jQuery illiterate. I don't know how to integrate this with my code. I was using (supposedly working) examples pulled from different posts that were not jQuery. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You don't need jQuery. I've updated my answer so it does not use jQuery.

Comment: I believe the audio.load(); audio.play(); should be with the new audioElement var. However, the audio control still loses scope. I've added audioElement.controls = true; so I can now see the control before it disappears...

Comment: I simplified the code down to basics, since I decided it should be working. Voila, the audio control does not lose scope. The bug is elsewhere. I will update when I find it.